Strong deviations in weight measurements, possibly after connecting a high current device on the same line
I have the following situation, where there's a sensitive scale connected to mains voltage (but they have their own AC-DC power supply).
Someone connected a device that requires very high power in the same hall and I got the following weights around that time:

The zoomed in view shows the following:

After 18:30, the values are jumping between a single low value and a range of high values. The sampling is very low (one values every minute).
For context, the values should actually platteau and not increase, hence why I took the min
I can mitigate the values with a rolling window of 1 h, but this is definitely not what I want to do to solve this problem. This is just for visualizing.
The cables carying the weight data from the scale to the laptop are shielded, so I guess normal EM interference can be excluded?
Could it be that the high current device loads the network in the whole hall to the point where this happens? How can I compensate this?
I have two other devices that show the same behaviour, only a camera was functioning normally (it was also connected to an AC-DC power supply in the same hall).
Thanks in advance for any hints!

After the comments, here's a link to the scale and below is my setup:

And here is the link to the power adapter

The high power device that is connected on the same network is a water heater (not kettle). The device is actually quite far and is not on the same metal surface. The water heater runs on 400 V (takes three phases) and has a max amperage of 30 amps. My colleague mentioned that they always run the heater at max amperage, so I guess the power consumption can reach up to 12kW.

Welcome! Everything is possible. What's your schematic and layout situation?

We really need to know a lot more about the scale. Model, manufacturer, pictures of how it’s set up, maybe pictures (clear and detailed) of the circuit inside the scale. If the scale is made of metal then there should be a good connection between the scale’s electronics, the metal it’s made of, and the metal it’s mounted on. So the setup - how the scale is installed and used - is very important too. I presume the data from the scale goes over USB. If not, how is the data acquired? If A DAQ card is used, grounding/shield/input configuration are suspect.

Thanks for the replies, I'll add more information about the scale.

Please edit the question to add those details, then flag the relevant comments as “no longer needed”. The obvious thing to try is to run the scale from a temporary battery to see whether the problem comes through the mains or not. Please also show whether the AC/DC supply is switching or transformer based, and whether it’s double insulated or not. Also, disconnect the supply from the scale and mains, and check with an ohmmeter if the DC side (any wire there) is shorted to the earth pin on the mains plug - if the supply is earthed.

Please also show the weight recording expanded in time scale so we can see how this interference looks like. The plot you show is compressed so that the real waveform is squeezed into vertical lines next to each other. That hides potentially useful information.

It will also help to know what high power device was used, and what it is connected to. Remember that connections can go through metal structures as well as via wires. So if the high power device was mounted on some metal frame and the scale was on the same metal frame - that may be how the problem developed.

@Kubahasn'tforgottenMonica Thanks for the very detailed comments, it will take me some time to do all of this stuff. I'll get back to this question and comment here again

Was the laptop charging while you did the measurements? And if yes was it plugged in a different or a distant mains socket than the scale?

@Rokta nice question, it was plugged in a different socket, but I think the same electric line is feeding both sockets

@Kubahasn'tforgottenMonica I updated the post and answered some of the stuff that you asked about. I hope this will be enough for now. For some of the other questions, I will do those things on Monday

I think shielded RS233 cable is part of a problem. I think you can solve problem by having laptop on battery power while you are doing the measurement or use RS232 isolator.

Thank you so much for the helpful comments!
After some testing today, I could identify surge current problems across the whole workshop when the water heater is turned on. One thing that I did not know is that it is both a heater and a pump, so there is an electric motor there as well.
I managed to reproduce the problem of fluctuating data points in my data export when the heater was turned on and off. Interestingly, the effect of the heater lasts a bit after it turns off, or maybe my the scale is sending me data that is a bit older than what I expect.
After using a surge protected socket in a UPS (APC Pro 900) to power the scale, the problem went away.
